# ASP.NET MVC: Simply can't seem to get any output. help!

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

In Visual Web Developer when I "run" my Controller (TestApp) I come up with this:

http://postimage.org/image/iggcs6hw/

I've tried adding "/TestApp" on the end of the local host address in the address bar and that gave me this result:

http://postimage.org/image/ih078cf8/

I don't think I've misspelled anything. Forgive me if this question is a stupid one, just trying to get my feet off the ground :D.

Comment: What does your routing look like? Does an Index view exist inside /Views/TestApp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have renamed the default `~/Views/Home` folder that was generated when you created your project into `~/Views/TestApp` folder. As far as the first error message is concerned make sure you have modified the default routes in `Global.asax` to make the `TestApp` controller the default one instead of `Home`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "TestApp", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

So to sum up:

- Make sure that you have an Index.aspx view inside the `~/Views/TestApp` folder.
- Make sure that you have set the `TestApp` controller in the default route in `Global.asax`
- Make sure that your TestApp controller has an `Index` action

Now you will be able to call your application like this: `http://example.com/` which will automatically call the `Index` action on `TestApp` controller which will render the `~/Views/TestApp/Index.aspx` view.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your views are in the /Views directory. MVC follows a strict folder structure and this happens when it can't find something.

When adding a new view or controller to an MVC project, it's best to use the wizard provided for that purpose.